# "If not for you" meaning

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, conditionals

Today I have encountered a phrase:

> If not for you, I would be poor.

I would think it is like "if there were not you", is it like that?

On the other hand, how would I say the following as the meaning would be different:

> If not for you, whom do I cook the cake for?

Comment: [Bob Dylan](http://www.songmeanings.net/songs/view/103402/) liked this idiom.

Comment: Incidentally, one *bakes* a cake.  If it goes in the oven it is *baked* (or broiled).  If it goes on the stove it is *cooked*.

Comment: You can cook some things in the oven, but sweet things (cakes, cookies, biscuits) are baked not cooked.

Comment: I suppose the first example employs an idiom. Leaving out 'it were/was' stretches the grammar (we don't say, for instance, 'If Ø a decision that would only affect my family and myself in the short term' [Ø shows the deleted 'it were'], if only to avoid the garden path): an extragrammatical idiom. But the second example shows an unmarked usage (except that the sentence is poor per se). 'If it's not for you, who _am_ I cooking the cake for?' or 'If we count you out, who _should_ i cook the cake for?'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The construction *If not for X* is an idiomatic phrase in English. The verb *to be* is normally left out when you use this construction, though if you restore it the full form would be:

> If it were not for you, I would be poor.

However, the original version without *it were* is also correct:

> If not for you, I would be poor.

Your version with *if there were not you* is grammatically incorrect. The construction *There is X* cannot be used with a pronoun in place of X under most circumstances.

Your example sentence *If not for you, whom do I cook the cake for?* is also correct, but this is a completely different construction which superficially resembles the one in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To me, "if not for you" means: If it were not for you to help, I would be poor.

The meaning of "it" is also clear (it means "to help").

Answer (score 0):

“Not for you” is an idiomatic expression that means.

1. It wasn’t designed with you in mind;
2. it is priced beyond your ability to pay;
3. you are not willing to pay the price;
4. it won’t work for you the way it will fit someone for whom it was designed.

Comment: The question was asking about "_if not for you_" which doesn't fit any of the above

Answer (score 0):

The first sample sentence and your last sample sentence are entirely different contexts.

The first can be paraphrased as, "If you had not been involved in my case, then I would still be poor."

The second can be paraphrased as, "If I'm not cooking for you, then who am I cooking for?"